# Writing PHP function and passing it a string

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am building a Wordpress theme and am onto displaying the custom fields of a custom post type. Instead of writing this a bunch of times:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_item', true)){ echo $post_meta_data['custom_item'][0]; } ?>
```

Can't I write a function to shorten this process? Something where I would pass it a variable and it can get plugged into the function. This is what I have so far with no luck:

```
<?php 
    function display_meta($custom_meta) {
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta, true)){ echo $post_meta_data[$custom_meta][0]; }} 
?>
```

And then I want to be able to do something like this for each field:

```
<?php echo display_meta('custom_item') ?>
```

I am still relatively new to PHP and this is my first time trying to write a function like this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I am still relatively new to PHP and this is my first time trying to write a function like this." -- http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need to pass $post and $post_meta_data to the function as well.

```
<?php 
function display_meta($custom_meta, $post, $post_meta_data) {
    if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $custom_meta, true)){ 
        echo $post_meta_data[$custom_meta][0]; 
    }
} 
?>
```

and you're attempting (incorrectly) to do an echo twice.  Something like this would work better

```
<?php display_meta('custom_item', $post, $post_meta_data) ?>
```

You should do some simple php tutorials and learn about functions and scoping tho.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking to do. I definitely will read up on it more. I just wanted to make sure I was heading in the right direction. Thanks, I noticed that I was echoing it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about closures which is available on php5.3

```
$myFunc = function()
{
  return 1;
};

function test($callback)
{
   if(is_callable($callback))
   {
      $callback();
   }
}

test($myFunc);
```